# T-SQL Distinct column problem when trying to filter duplicates out

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, distinct-values

I have the following data

```
COL-1     COL-2

1        0TY/OK
1        0TY/OK
1        0TY/OK 
1        0TY/OK 
1        0TY/OK
2        2KP/L         
2        2KP/L
2        2KP/L  
2        2KP/L       
2        2KP/L      
3        7U5/2M
3        7U5/2M 
3        7U5/2M 
3        7U5/2M
```

And i want to construct a select query to retrieve that data in the output below

```
COL-1     COL-2        COL-3

1        0TY/OK      0TY/OK
1        0TY/OK      2KP/L  
1        0TY/OK      7U5/2M
1        0TY/OK 
1        0TY/OK
2        2KP/L         
2        2KP/L
2        2KP/L  
2        2KP/L       
2        2KP/L      
3        7U5/2M
3        7U5/2M 
3        7U5/2M 
3        7U5/2M
```

I want COL3 to return the distinct values of COL2

Using `SELECT COL1, COL2, DISTINCT COL2 AS COL3 FROM MYTable` does not work is SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm sure that some SQL wizard will be able to construct a way to do this, I feel the need to point out that conceptually this doesn't make sense - the values in the rows of column 3 are completely unrelated to the row values in columns 1 and 2.

Can you not simply return the distinct values of COL2 in a separate query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL2 FROM MyTable
```

(Note that you can return multiple resultsets from a single SQL query)

Comment: I want to use the distinct values in COL3 as the available values for a paramater in my SSRS 2005 report. 

I could have added a seperate query, but unfortunately, i have to do this in one dataset because SQL Server 2005 reporting services does not allow multiple datasets in a single rdl report.

Is it possible to have two separate queries in a single SSRS 2005 report dataset?

Comment: @Name.IsNullOrEmpty - I see, I'd like to suggest an alternative however I'm not that familiar with SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

This is really unusual, and I can't see why you want this in one result set as it does not make any sense... There is no reason to associate the rows of the distinct query with the rows in the non-distinct query., but what you have to do is simply run both queries

```
Select Col1, Col2 From Table
Order By Col1, Col2
```

And

```
Select Distinct Col2 From Table
```

and join them together (To join them on row number, add a Row_Number() function to each query:

```
   Select Col1, Col2, Col3
   From   (Select Row_Number() Over(Order By Col1, Col2)RowNum, 
               Col1, Col2 
           From Table) T1
     Left Join 
          (Select Distinct Col2 As Col3,
           (Select Count(Distinct Col2)
            From Table
            Where Col2 <= T2.Col3) RowNum                    
           From Table) T2
        On T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum
```

Comment: Col3 still returns duplicate values

Comment: Didnlt realize this, but for some reason, Row_Number function is hinky with a Distinct in the query... reverted to old style Row Number subquery expression....

Comment: Am getting error "The multi-part identifier "T2.Col2" could not be bound." at this line, 


 

(Where Col2 <= T2.Col2) RowNum)

Comment: Try it now that should have been  `(Where Col2 <= T2.Col3) RowNum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTEs to create a ROW_NUMBER and JOIN over those virtual columns.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
   Col1 INT
   ,Col2 VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, '0TY/OK');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, '0TY/OK');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, '0TY/OK');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, '0TY/OK');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, '0TY/OK');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, '2KP/L,');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, '2KP/L');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, '2KP/L');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, '2KP/L');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, '2KP/L');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3, '7U5/2M');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3, '7U5/2M');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3, '7U5/2M');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3, '7U5/2M');

; WITH all_data AS (
   SELECT
      Col1
      ,Col2
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNum
   FROM @t
),
distinct_data AS (
   SELECT
      Col2
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNum
   FROM @t
   GROUP BY
      Col2
)
SELECT
   all_data.Col1
   ,all_data.Col2
   ,distinct_data.Col2
FROM all_data
   LEFT JOIN distinct_data ON all_data.RowNum = distinct_data.RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

```
WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT 1 Col1,CONVERT (VarChar (25), '0TY/OK') Col2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'0TY/OK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'0TY/OK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'0TY/OK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'0TY/OK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'2KP/L' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'2KP/L' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'2KP/L' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'2KP/L' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'2KP/L' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'7U5/2M' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'7U5/2M' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'7U5/2M' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'7U5/2M'
)
,
AllData AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Col2) as Id
    FROM MyTable
)
,
DistinctData AS
(
        SELECT 
            Distinct Col2 AS Col3
        FROM MyTable
),
DistinctWithRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Col3) as Id
    FROM DistinctData
)
SELECT 
    Col1, 
    Col2, 
    Col3
FROM AllData
    LEFT JOIN DistinctWithRowNumber 
        ON AllData.Id = DistinctWithRowNumber.Id
```

returns this result

```
Col1        Col2                      Col3
----------- ------------------------- -------------------------
1           0TY/OK                    0TY/OK
1           0TY/OK                    2KP/L
1           0TY/OK                    7U5/2M
1           0TY/OK                    NULL
1           0TY/OK                    NULL
2           2KP/L                     NULL
2           2KP/L                     NULL
2           2KP/L                     NULL
2           2KP/L                     NULL
2           2KP/L                     NULL
3           7U5/2M                    NULL
3           7U5/2M                    NULL
3           7U5/2M                    NULL
3           7U5/2M                    NULL
```